# upload video to firebase storage emulator

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to implement a file upload feature in my Angular app using the Firebase Storage/Hosting/Auth emulator.
My solution works for images, but when I try to upload larger files likes videos, I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Template:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
```

Code:

```
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage)

onFileChange(fileChangeEvent: Event) {    
    const target = fileChangeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const file = (target.files as FileList)[0];
    const filePath = file.name;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = fileRef.put(file);
}
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
        }
    }
}
```

After the upload attempt of any video, a file is added to the Storage emulator, but it always has file size 262.14 kB and is of type application/octet-stream.

What is going on here?

Comment: After deploying it to a test server, the implementation works. I only have this problem in the firebase storage emulator.

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4982